# Установка GMP для Visual Studio

Tags: c++, библиотеки

Помогите разобраться, как установить библиотеку GMP для использования в Visual Studio.

На [хабре](https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/53707/) нашел статью подробную, но возникла проблема. У меня нет папки `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\`. У меня даже папки Microsoft Visual Studio нет. Ни на диске C, ни на диске D куда я и устанавливал студию.

Может кто нибудь в виде ответа написать подробнейшую инструкцию по установке. Я думаю это будет полезно не одному мне.

Answer (score 0):

Установи [Microsoft Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/downloads/), и папка появится. Посмотри в **Program Files (x86)**.

Нужно ставить старую версию Visual Studio 2008 или 2010. Почитай [здесь](http://www.freepascal.ru/article/freepascal/20190411080000/).

> С Windows не всё так просто. К примеру, на моём рабочем компьютере с Windows уже стояла система CYGWIN в которой, судя по сообщению инсталлятора, "libgmp" была установлена по умолчанию. Ну, хорошо, компилирую примеры - всё прекрасно компилируется. Запускаю и, ёлки зелёные, получаю системное окошко с сообщением, что у меня отсутствует "gmp.dll". После некоторых размышлений и поисков выяснилось, что "libgmp" всё-таки стоит, вот только называется она почему-то "cyggmp-10.dll". Ну, ладно, сделал я ей новое имя, то которе положено - "libgmp.dll". Запускаю тестовую программу, ошибок больше не появляется, зато, программа зависла и не работает. Мало того, с помощью "Ctrl-C" завершить её невозможно, пришлось лезть в диспетчер задач.
>   Плюнув на CYGWIN я решил разжиться библиотекой в MINGW . Имя у неё оказалось вполне нормальным, хотя и не каноническим - "libgmp-10.dll", так что опять пришлось переименовывать. Слегка мандражируя, снова запускаю тестовый пример и - свершилось чудо - пример отработал так, как нужно. Значит библиотеку 'libgmp" от MINGW можно без большого количества телодвижений спокойно использовать в Windows.

Comment: Очень емкий ответ. Но выдимо не совсем на этот вопрос. Так как автор уже указывал в вопросе что он устанавливал Microsoft Visual Studio и даже указал куда.

Comment: Ему нужен VC, а значить надо установить компонент. Кроме этого его статья за 2012 год и установка уже другая. Так что либо компонет ставить либо старую версию Visual Studio

Comment: Напишите эту информацию в Ваш ответ. А то Ваши рекомендации расходятся с вопросом который задает автор. Соответственно это его может ввести в заблуждение, впрочем как и остальных участников сообщества.

Comment: @MakarX а не могли бы в виде ответа написать новую установку. И да в папке x86 есть папка Microsoft Visual Studio но в ней еще 2 папки Installer и Shared. А в них еще по 2 папки и в них уже есть по инструкции link.exe и lib.exe, но их 4 штуки получается. И я пробовал с одной из, но вылетала ошибка.

Comment: Конечно, интересный пример, но все же мне бы хотя бы установить, а потом ошибки исправлять. И скачивать другую версию студии этот вариант мне не подходит.